# unexpected results when comparing Biostrings subsequences using the identical function

Tags: r, string, bioconductor, dna-sequence

I'm checking if a sequence is present at the beginning and at the end of a longer sequence. I considered using `identical` but this gives me a surprising result:

```
library(Biostrings)

EcoRI <- DNAString("GAATTC")
myseq <- DNAString("GAATTCGGGGAAAATTTTCCCCGAATTC")

EcoRI
#  6-letter "DNAString" instance
#seq: GAATTC

subseq(myseq, 1, 6)
#  6-letter "DNAString" instance
#seq: GAATTC

subseq(myseq, 23, 28)
#  6-letter "DNAString" instance
#seq: GAATTC

identical(EcoRI, subseq(myseq, 1, 6))
#TRUE

identical(EcoRI, subseq(myseq, 23, 28)) 
#FALSE

identical(subseq(myseq, 1, 6), subseq(myseq, 23, 28)) 
#FALSE
```

An easy fix is to use:

```
identical(toString(EcoRI), toString(subseq(myseq, 23, 28)))
# TRUE
```

But I don't understand why `identical` on the `DNAString` objects returns `FALSE` sometimes.
Does `identical` also compare the `offset` attributes?

```
attributes(EcoRI)$offset
#[1] 0
attributes(subseq(myseq, 1, 6))$offset
#[1] 0
attributes(subseq(myseq, 23, 28))$offset
#[1] 22
```

Comment: `identical` compares objects, in all their details. Therefore it also compares attributes. Even cases like `identical(1:3, seq(1, 3))` versus `identical(1:3, seq(1, 3, by = 1))` can be surprising.

Comment: Thank you @RuiBarradas. cf also [R inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). What surprises me here is that the `offset` attribute seems to be taken into account by the `identical` function but not the `shared` attribute (containing the address of the original sequence). Since both attributes are related to the original sequence I don't understand why only one of them is taken into account by `identical`.